# Changing key name inside foreach

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I'm wanting to edit an array key name, changing it from a date into it's numeric order id, and throwing the date inside the array.

```
  [entries] => Array
        (
            [2015-07-19] => Array
                (
                    [value] => 14.8
                )

            [2015-07-18] => Array
                (
                    [value] => 14.9
                )
```

Into

```
  [entries] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [value] => 14.8
                    [date] => 2015-07-19
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [value] => 14.9
                    [date] => 2015-07-18
                )
```

Comment: Have you tried anything to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
$entries = array(
     '2015-07-19' => array(
          'value' => 14.8
     ),
     '2015-07-18' => array(
          'value' => 14.9
     )
);
$result = array();
foreach ($entries as $key => $value) {
     $result['entries'][] = array('date'=> $key, 'value' => $value['value']);
}
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion (without creating new array):

```
$entries = array(
    '2015-07-19' => array ('value' => 14.8),
    '2015-07-18' => array ('value' => 14.9),        
);

foreach ($entries as $key => &$entry) 
{
    $entry['date'] = $key;
}
unset($entry);

$entries = array_values($entries);
```